# For incoming http request the content-length > 0 but request.getParameterNames is no data

Tags: java, servlets, jboss5.x

When I send a http request to JBoss 5.1.0 GA by form post method and I print the all parameter names and request content-length in console, sometimes request parameter names and content-length match each other very well. But in the other occasions, content-length shows the correct result and request parameter names disappear.

I use wireshark to sniff client to make sure the http posted data is correct. However, looks like the webserver side loses part of request data from time to time.

Is it probably related to the posted data's size  is too large?

Do you guys know the possible reasons?

Comment: You will need to post example request messages and code snippets. Otherwise we don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: from time to time? do you have a specific set of values that can replicate the issue on demand?